# Why are parts of my html code not following the CSS but others are

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a school project and i have this one same peace of html code pasted three times the first two follow the CSS fine but the last one doesn't even though they are all the exact same

[an image of my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4UkN.png)

this is the code that i have pasted three times but for some reason the CSS doesn't apply to the last one so the page looks like this

[an image of my output om my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uAsX.png)

I don't know much about HTML but from research on W3schools and on stack overflow i couldn't find a solution

Comment: provide the code pls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the guide on how to ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question accordingly. Most importantly is the section about not posting images of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you are opening an `<ol>` (in the middle of your first screenshot)
with a `class` named "list".

I'm pretty sure it's the reason why your third paragraph isn't acting normally. Close it or delete it and tell me if it worked !

Comment: Thank you so much i am only learning html and was unaware of key words that couldn't be used for classes, this really helped